How do I make my resources dynamic in anylogic?
I want to dynamically adjust the number of resources in a resource pool using a slider. The available resources also depends on time (working hours). Unfortunately, the value within a schedule block cannot be set to a parameter. Does anyone know how to solve this?


The ResourcePool can be changed in size using the set_Capacity(int value) method.
Beware, though: if you reduce the number, you have no control which resources get destroyed.
